# How can I make a warn command take everything after the Users ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a working discord bot that can warn people and insert a reason and their id into a database. What i cant figure out is how to make every argument after the mention the reason.

```
@bot.command(name="warn")
async def warn(ctx, user: discord.User, reason):
    uid = user.id
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Staff")
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        warn = await bot.db.create_warn(int(uid), reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Warned @"+str(uid), description=f"reason: {reason}", color=0x0c0f27)
```

Everything works fine, i just need the reason to be everything after the user mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add a `*` argument before `reason`:

```py
@bot.command(name="warn")
async def warn(ctx, user: discord.User, *, reason):
    uid = user.id
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Staff")
    if role in ctx.author.roles:
        warn = await bot.db.create_warn(int(uid), reason)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Warned @"+str(uid), description=f"reason: {reason}", color=0x0c0f27)
```

Reference : [Keyword Only Arguments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)